# Passing a value in onclick function for loop generated elements

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener

I would like to pass a parameter (string from resultset) to an onClick function for a generated link.

Right now I have this:

```
for (var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
      var attend= document.createElement("a");
      var name = response.data[i].name;
      attend.innerHTML="Add event";
      attend.addEventListener("click", function() {saveEvent(name);}, false);
      document.getElementsByClassName("event")[i].appendChild(attend);
}
```

This results in me always getting the last element name whichever link I click on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because a closure is being created around the `name` variable. This makes the data that variable holds shared among all the event handler functions. The reason you are always seeing the last element's `name` is because that's the last value the `name` property had stored in it when the loop finished.

You need to pass a copy of that data upon each loop iteration. Change the code to use **[`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)** instead of `var` for the variable declaration so that upon each iteration of the loop, `name` will have its own scope.

Closures can be a tricky concept to get your head around. You can read more about them **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)**.

```
for (var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
      var attend= document.createElement("a");
      let name = response.data[i].name;
      attend.innerHTML="Add event";
      attend.addEventListener("click", function() {saveEvent(name);}, false);
      document.getElementsByClassName("event")[i].appendChild(attend);
}
```

Beyond that, modifying the DOM is already an expensive operation in terms of performance. Doing it in a loop, just compounds that. You should use a **[`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)** inside the loop and then append that just once when the loop is done.

Comment: Thank you so much, that definitely solved my problem! I don't have a lot of time left to optimize in terms of performance but I'll take a look after I'm done!